# How to resolve “ invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'LPSTR {aka char*}' [-fpermissive] "

Tags: c, winapi, lpstr

I use Qt Creator and this code :

```
CreateProcess(NULL,string("curl -F \"api_key=XXX\" -F \"filetype=mp3\" -F \"track=@"+execpath+"\\sound.mp3\" \"http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/upload\"").c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &startupinfo, &procinfo); // Send sound.mp3 to be analyzed by Echonest
```

generate this issue:

```
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'LPSTR {aka char*}
```

How to solve it?

Note that I have defined :

```
DEFINES -= UNICODE
```

in my .pro file

Comment: note that execpath is a string

Comment: solved,
I've converted to LPSTR :
CreateProcess(NULL,(LPSTR) string("...

Comment: Don't do that; it's not a solution. If the parameter is non-const, it means the function can change it. You don't want it changing a string's `c_str()`. Give the function something that can be modified.

Comment: Qt Creator is an IDE. It's use is not very relevant here. Perhaps it is a Qt project - then you should be using `QProcess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read documentation on [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) carefully. Second argument is marked as `inout`, meaning the function would (in this case, could) modify the value pointed to.

If you're going to make a cast the way you mention in comments, it is better to not only add a comment but also probably use ANSI function explicitly (thus calling `CreateProcessA()`) just in case.

Also, Qt has its own way of creating processes. You could refer to [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) documentation.